# merge nested list by first value in each list in python

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a version of this code working but it seems overly complex.  This is the simplified version im getting stuck on.   in python3.

```
list1 = [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 't'], ['x', 'f'], ['x', 'g'], ['d', 'z']]

z = len(list1)
for i in range(0, z):
    for j in range(i + 1, z):
        while list1[i][0] == list1[j][0]:
            list1[i] = list1[i] + [list1[j][-1]]
            if list1[j] in list1:
                list1.remove(list1[j])
                z = z - 1
```

I want output.

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 't'], ['x', 'f', 'g'], ['d', 'z']]
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic

Comment: merge the lists with same first value without copying the first value.  Im only interested in an easily readable code to do that.  If there is a better way thats even better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modding Darryl's a bit:

```
d = {}
for head, *tail in lst:
    d.setdefault(head, [head]).extend(tail)

lst2 = list(d.values())
```

Answer (score 2):

A simplfied construction is the following two steps.

```
d = {}
for sublist in lst:
  d.setdefault(sublist[0], []).extend(sublist[1:])

lst2 = [[k] + v for k, v in d.items()]

print(lst2)
>>> [['a', 'b', 'c', 't'], ['x', 'f', 'g'], ['d', 'z']]
```

**Explanation**

(1) Dictionary d places items with the same first element as a dictionary key, with values corresponding to the remaining elements to produce:

```
{'a': ['b', 'c', 't'], 'x': ['f', 'g'], 'd': ['z']}
```

(2) Next, the list comprehension uses the key of each dictionary entry as the first element of a sublist and the value of the items as the remaining elements to produce the desired result