# python - merge list according to the first element

Tags: python, list

I have a list in a list:
`[[1, 4],[1, 7],[2, 4],[5, 0]]`

I am trying to merge it so it looks like this:
`[[1, 4, 7],[2, 4],[5, 0]]`

What is the best way to 'merge' this single list into this? Thanks

Comment: So you’re saying you want to merge adjacent lists or any list? And will there be duplicate values in the list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge nested list by first value in each list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012337/merge-nested-list-by-first-value-in-each-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure abut "the best", but I would use an auxiliary dictionary:

```
lst = [[1, 4],[1, 7],[2, 4],[5, 0]]
d = {}
for l in lst:
  if l[0] in d:
    d[l[0]].extend(l[1:])
  else:
    d[l[0]] = l
result = list(d.values())
```

This method is probably faster than any other, however it may do strange things to the order of sublists due to the fact dictionaries are not ordered.

Comment: Just fyi, starting version 3.6 the dicts keep their input order

Comment: many thanks, both solutions worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do the grouping using a dict:

```
lst = [[1, 4], [1, 7], [2, 4], [5, 0]]
output_dict = {}
for i in lst:
    if i[0] not in outout_dict:
        output_dict[i[0]] = [i[0]]
    output_dict[i[0]].append(i[1])
```

To make it into a list, simply use:

```
output_lst = list(output_dict.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Well to put it simple

```py
# init 
list1 = [[1, 4],[1, 7],[2, 4],[5, 0]] 
list2 = [] 
# add all first values to list2 
for val in list1: 
    if not val[0] in list2: 
       list2.append(val[0]) 
list2 = [[x] for x in list2] 
# begin the ordering 
for val in list1: 
    for i in list2: 
        if val[0] == i[0]: 
            i.extend(val[1:]) 
list2
```

`>>> [[1, 4, 7],[2, 4],[5, 0]]`
This does the job fine for me.

Comment: Pure listing, im a bad coder, dont hurt me